How to assign permissions to all EC2 instances in an account?
I'm setting up the CloudWatch agent to gather additional ec2 metrics across all instances in our accounts. The agent is already installed in our AMI
To do this for a single instance I needed to attach an IAM role with the correct permissions using policy CloudWatchAgentAdminPolicy.
Is there some way I can add this permission to all EC2 instances without having to individually attach or edit the roles to each ec2 instance?
Using Default Host Management Configuration like suggested below it does get rid of the permission error for ec2:DescribeTags but I now get this error seemingly suggesting there is no role associated with the ec2 instance (I have not attached a role but assumed the DHMC would act as a role?)

2024-09-22T15:22:51Z E! [outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Aws error received
when sending logs to /aws/ec2/lp-cl-logs/i-019bcb8a28594532f:
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain caused by:
EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, . EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2
instance role found caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make
EC2Metadata request 
  
   404 - Not Found       404 -
Not Found
    status code: 404, request id:



Yes, you can use Default Host Management Configuration, which is part of the AWS Systems Manager service.
This allows Systems Manager to manage your Amazon EC2 instances automatically as managed instances, including assigning a default IAM role to them when launched. A default IAM role is created with the necessary SSM permissions but you can add additional, custom permissions e.g. for CloudWatch Logs.
See Managing EC2 instances automatically with Default Host Management Configuration.
Also see A role for all your EC2 instances.

I see, and what happens if the user attaches another role to the instance after the creation?
I will play around with this and see if it works.

I tried this approach but got another error, put it in the description.

Recommend that you try this with a new, basic EC2 instance to verify how it all works. And be sure to review the pre-requisites.
